# Change properties of view associate with gesture - SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, gesture

I would like to change the font of the emoji that has been tapped.

```
...

1 var body: some View {
2    GeometryReader { geometry in
3        ForEach(self.dataSet.emojis) { emoji in
4           Text(emoji)
5               .font(Font.system(size: 3))
6               .position(self.position(for: emoji, in: geometry.size))
7                    .gesture(
8                        TapGesture()
9                            .onEnded { action in
10                                
11                                // Here I would like to enlarge the
                            font of Text in line 4 without adding a new one.
12                                })
```

Comment: Do mean change the font of the particular emoji or for the whole text emoji?

Comment: @RajaKishan I have emojis flying around on the screen. I would like to enrage the text of the emoji that has been clicked.

Comment: then it's better to add one more property to the model i.e. font property. and on tap change font for the selected element of an array.

Comment: Great idea! Thank you @RajaKishan!